# Extra output lines when calling SQL scripts from bacth file

Tags: sql, batch-file

I have a batch file where I am passing a value to SQL and then executing the SQL query. I am getting desired output but additionally few more lines also appearing in the output.

Batch File

```dos
set /p hostname="Enter hostname:"
echo %hostname%
set arg1=
set arg1=%arg1: =%
set COMMAND=sqlplus.exe -s %arg1% 
%COMMAND% @C:\Users\infodba\Desktop\test.sql %hostname%
```

SQL file

```sql
select ID from Tablename where pid = '&1';
```

Here I am passing hostname to query as "&1" and I get this output:

```
old   1: select ID  from Tablename where pid='&1'     //extra lines
new   1: select ID from Tablename  where pid='SQY5760dznicWC'   //extra lines

SQY5760dznicWC/08_01_0_pdf_23o0akf8jwgy6.pdf    //desired output.
```

but if I remove the &1 and pass the hostname directly, I am not getting those extra lines.

Please help me figure out how to remove those extra lines.

Comment: As it is technically not the cause of your issue, I decided to just leave a comment to say that your batch file is very poor. Every line it contains can be improved, and there are lines missing which should be included in a robust interactive script.

Answer (score 1):

You can suppress the variable substitution line by setting `VERIFY` to `OFF` using following command:

```
SET VERIFY OFF
```

You need to write this command in your sql script.

Answer (score 1):

```
%COMMAND% @C:\Users\infodba\Desktop\test.sql %hostname%|find /v ":"
```

should suppress those lines. Can't test on my machine, so theory only.